# SSRS: IF Else inside Switch not working

Tags: reporting-services, oracle10g, ssrs-2008

- Here im trying to do switch then if else in it. I dont know where i missed but this doesnt work.
- for first condition in switch, 'WEEKLY', WW2 and WW1 is in number form but of text/string datatype. so after cast them to integer/number datatype then those are use in iff operation.
- for second condition in switch, 'MONTHLY', WW2 and WW1 is month name. so the objective is to get month number from month name. After that, then WW1,WW2 are use in iff operation.

`=SWITCH(Parameters!date_range_type.Value = "WEEKLY", IIF((cInt(Parameters!WW2.Value) - cInt(Parameters!WW1.Value)) > 10, Parameters!WW1.Value,IIF(cInt(Parameters!WW2.Value) < 11,1,cInt(Parameters!WW2.Value) - 10)),
Parameters!date_range_type.Value = "MONTHLY", IIF((cInt(MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW2.Value & "-01")) - cInt(MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW1.Value & "-01"))) > 10, MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW1.Value & "-01"),IIF(cInt(MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW2.Value & "-01")) < 11,1,cInt(MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW2.Value & "-01")) - 10))
)`

if i run report for 'WEEKLY' only, means doesnt need switch and the other iif condition, it working fine. so does when run on 'MONTHLY' only.

**EDIT**

this is how it looks like if i use iif only..

`IIF(Parameters!date_range_type.Value = "MONTHLY",( IIF((cInt(MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW2.Value & "-01")) - cInt(MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW1.Value & "-01"))) > 10,MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW1.Value & "-01"),IIF(cInt(MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW2.Value & "-01")) < 11,1,cInt(MONTH(datepart("YYYY",today())& "-" & Parameters!WW2.Value & "-01")) - 10)) ),
( IIF(Parameters!date_range_type.Value = "WEEKLY",( IIF((cInt(Parameters!WW2.Value) - cInt(Parameters!WW1.Value)) > 10, Parameters!WW1.Value,
        IIF(cInt(Parameters!WW2.Value) < 11,1,cInt(Parameters!WW2.Value) - 10)) ), "0") ) )`

Comment: Despite all that text above it's not clear what your desired output is. If I'm correct you select weekly or monthly that gives you either a week number(?) Or month name respectively. What do you want out of the other end of the calculation?

Comment: WW1 and WW2 is both supplied with list of respective date_range_type whether weekly or monthly in current year. for weekly type, first action before proceed to iif is to cast WW1 and WW2 to number so that then could do math opr on both value. while monthly, because value supplied is in month name, it has to be converted to month number then cast to number.

Comment: the expression above would output a number that the range between output and WW2 value is always try to be greater or equal to 10, if not the output is value which difference is 10 and lower than WW2.output depends on range between WW1 and WW2 which means is difference in value between WW1 and WW2.when the difference is greater than 10 output will take value of WW1, if less then if WW2 is less than 11 output is fixed to 1 (because while range between output and WW2 need to be at least 10, date range is valid only as low as 1 which represent work week 1 or first month)

Comment: You can't convert a month name to a number in SSRS (very easily). It is much better to keep the type of the data as a date or an int and just display our as a string when presenting it to the user

Comment: i think its doable but require more syntax like this =MONTH("<YYYY-MON-DD>") . Above exp maybe too complex to put in SSRS(for readability/debug), i think ill just put everything in sql proc instead. ill keep your advice to make it simple for SSRS. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up using sql function for the job. this is the same logic as above SSRS code.

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ww3_param (ww1 IN NUMBER, ww2 IN NUMBER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
ret_val VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
   IF (ww2 - ww1) > 10 THEN
     ret_val := to_char(ww1);
   ELSE
     IF ww2 < 10 THEN
       ret_val := '1';
     ELSE 
       ret_val := to_char(ww2 - 10);

     END IF; 
   END IF;

   RETURN ret_val;
END;`

**EDIT**

This is the query for the dataset:

`select case when :date_range_type = 'MONTHLY' then ww3_param(to_char(to_date(:WW1,'MON'),'MM'),to_char(to_date(:WW2,'MON'),'MM')) 
when :date_range_type = 'WEEKLY' then ww3_param(to_number(:WW1),to_number(:WW2)) end as ww3_param_value
from dual`

Comment: Looks like Oracle syntax? Can you confirm it is Oracle and I will tag your question accordingly

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes it is oracle. 10g version. thanks.